# Call C++ function using Python ctypes with py_object argument

Tags: python, exception, ctypes

I get an access violation.  I am using a c++ dll with a single function that tries to extract a string from a PyObject.  It seems the PyObject *args argument is not right type.  This is from similar examples posted elsewhere.  Passing a c_char_p (to a function taking a c_char_p) and returning a PyObject * works fine.

Load a C++ dll and call a function with an object.  Set correct path.

Using msvc 2022 and Python 3.9.

Python (using PYFUNCTYPE or CFUNCTYPE makes no difference):

```
import ctypes
import sys
import os 

y = __file__
str_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("..\\..\\string\\x64\\Debug\\string.dll"))
handle = ctypes.CDLL(str_path + "/string.dll")     

handle.My_Function3.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]
handle.My_Function3.restype = ctypes.py_object

z = handle.My_Function3(y)

print(z)
```

Create C++ string.dll adding a single function.  I have verified the addresses is correctly passed through, but then I get internal errors in the function.

C++ file added to string.dll (added to Windows dll) dllmain.cop is unchanged:

function.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

char s[100];

static PyObject *MyError;

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) PyObject* __stdcall My_Function3(PyObject *args)
    {
        const char* str;
        char s[100];

        // Code fails here with access violation
        if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &str))
            return NULL;
 
        if (strlen(str) > 100)
        {
            PyErr_SetString(MyError, "Error: string too long");
            return NULL;
        }

        strcat_s(s, 100, str);
        return Py_BuildValue("s", s);
    }
}
```

Modifying the code a little bit shows the error to be in the exception handling.  (I have since gotten this example to work as an extension with the necessary changes for the string copy.)

[image]

Comment: If this is 32bit Python and DLL, you must replace `__stdcall` by `__cdecl`.

Comment: Thanks, 64 bit, __cdecl makes no difference.

Comment: @MichaelButscher And if 32-bit, you would use `WinDLL` instead of `CDLL` for `__stdcall` functions...and should anyway in 64-bit if portability to 32-bit is important.

Comment: To call a function that uses the Python C API, use `PyDLL`.  It won't release the GIL when calling into a C function, unlike `CDLL/WinDLL`.  FYI `PyDLL` expects `__cdecl` calling convention.  You should use the right one, even on 64-bit for portability to 32-bit.

Comment: FYI, `char s[100];` is uninitialized (and shadows the global duplicate).  I'd expect `strcat_s` to have issues.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I know. I asked because of the mismatch of `CDLL` and `__stdcall`.

Comment: Thanks, the code dies long before that.  Changing the code to check the "O" type still gives an error.  The code dies in the exception handling.

Comment: The code dies before that makes a difference.  Passing a c_int causes no problems because none of the Py* functions are called on objects passed in.  Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone have a piece of code that passes a py_object into c++ using ctypes that works on windows?  I went to work of creating an extension.  That works fine, but knowing if ctypes.py_object as an argument works on windows would be nice.

Comment: if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &str)) should possibly return 0, not raise an exception.  The args variable contains the same address value in c++ and python, so should be the correct object.

Comment: @user23317703 Again, use `PyDLL` for proper GIL handling and `__cdecl` for correctness (yes, `__stdcall` will work on 64-bit but breaks portability).  `py_object` will work.  I've used it many times.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PyDLL` for proper GIL handling and `__cdecl` for correctness (yes, `__stdcall` will work on 64-bit but breaks portability).  `py_object` will work.  Here's an example calling `PyArg_ParseTuple` itself:

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.PyDLL('python3')
dll.PyArg_ParseTuple.argtypes = ct.py_object, ct.c_char_p
dll.PyArg_ParseTuple.restype = ct.c_int

a1 = ct.c_char_p()
a2 = ct.c_int()
print('result:', dll.PyArg_ParseTuple(('abc一二三', 123), b'si', ct.byref(a1), ct.byref(a2)))
print(a1.value, a1.value.decode(), a2.value)
```

Output:

```
result: 1
b'abc\xe4\xb8\x80\xe4\xba\x8c\xe4\xb8\x89' abc一二三 123
```